# How to remove Special Character ^M using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt

Trying to remove `^M`. I am not sure whether this can be done via XSLT or regress.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" >^M
    <soapenv:Header>^M

    </soapenv:Header>^M
    <soapenv:Body>^M
        <urn:getTargetingInfo>^M
            <getTargetingInfoRequest>^M
                <inCID>202020</inCID>^M     
                <inAttributeType/>^M
            </getTargetingInfoRequest>^M
        </urn:getTargetingInfo>^M
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: That's not a well-formed XML: the `urn` prefix is not bound to a namespace URI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[starts-with(., '^M')]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```